# Does every function that is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ admit a primitive?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, indefinite-integrals

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Does exist a function $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$? In compact intervals is clear, because of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Can this be extended to the whole real line? In other words, let $a\in \mathbb{R}$. Consider
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt
$$
If $a<x$, then $F'(x) = f(x)$, because of FTC. What if $a>x$?

Thoughts: let $b<x$. Then $\int_a^x f(t) dt - \int_b^x f(t) dt \in \mathbb{R}$. The second integral $G(x) = \int_b^x f(t) dt$ verifies $G'(x) = f(x)$ $\forall x>b$, so is a primitive of $f$. Since $F(x)$ differs by a constant from a primitive in $(b,\infty)$, then is also a primitive in $(b,\infty)$.

Is my reasoning ok?

Comment: @DARK I don't quite understand you... I did not ask for an example of a continuous function having a primitive, I asked about whether all functions that are continuous in $\mathbb{R}$ have a primitive.

Comment: Why doesn't that work across all of $\mathbb{R}$?  $F(x)$ exists since $[a,x]$ is compact.

Comment: By definition (but for better reasons than just "because we defined it that way"), $\int_a^x f(t)dt = -\int_x^a f(t)dt$. With this fact, FTC holds for your original function even in the situation that $x\leqslant a$, without the need for the introduction of $b$.

Comment: Just take $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt,\,\,x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: @jwhite And the derivative of $-\int_x^a f(t)dt$ is $f(t)$ when $x<a$? Is this suppose to be obvious from the FTC?

Comment: FTC says $\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x f(t)dt=f(x)$, as long as $f$ is continuous on $[\min\{a,x\},\max\{a,x\}]$, regardless of which one is bigger.

Comment: The proof of FTC involves expressions of the form $$\int_a^{x+\delta}f(t)dt - \int_a^x f(t)dt= \int_x^{x+\delta} f(t)dt,$$ so $a$ doesn't matter when computing the derivative. These expressions don't change based on what side of $a$ $x$ is on.